# Looking for the complete Happy Days Spin Off Tree

Tags: happy-days, spin-off

I believe (but it is like fodder for another question) that Happy Days may be part of the largest spin-off tree in TV History (To the date of this posting)

Is there a compiled list or graphic of the tree? (Noting that HD was a spin off so if it's parent Love American Style had other spin-offs, then they belong on the tree as well.

Comment: All in the Family has a pretty large one, too.

Comment: Arrested Development  probably isn't considered a Happy Days spin-off, but it almost should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, a little bit of research turns up this hierarchy:

```
    Love, American Style
        Happy Days
            The Fonz and the Happy Days gang (animated)
            Out of the Blue
            Laverne & Shirley
                Laverne & Shirley in the Army (animated)
            Mork & Mindy
                Mork & Mindy (animated)
            Joanie Loves Chachi
            Blanksy's Beauties
        Wait Till Your Father Gets Home
```

The Mork and Mindy animated was actually a combo with the other two animated series.  But it seems like the hierarchy ends there.

I also found [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_spin-offs) that may help identify those with more spinoffs, but it doesn't appear comprehensive.

Comment: Wasn't Happy Days also a by-product of the success of American Graffiti?

Comment: Well, movies like American Graffiti and Grease ushered in the nostalgia for the 50's that allowed Happy Days to be successful.  But, beyond that serendipitous influence, I can't find any other relationship between the two.

Comment: Yes but the rest of the "Love American Style" spin offs need to be there as well.

Comment: Well, there are some sites that list Barefoot in the Park and Wait Till Your Father Gets Home as spinoffs.  I've added the latter to my answer, but I don't believe the former qualifies as the neither the characters nor the story appear to have originated on Love, American Style.

Comment: Great stuff Jacob. Can you edit the answer to include the links you are referencing? Thanks!

Comment: @JacobG "I can't find any other relationship between the two." – The fact that Ron Howard starred in both American Graffiti and Happy Days doesn't count? ;) Reading up on the history, Happy Days started as an unsold pilot that Paramount rejected, George Lucas asked to see the pilot to determine if Ron Howard would be suitable for his movie, then Garry Marshall recast the pilot to turn Happy Days into a series.

Comment: @ghoppe - Technically, I don't think that does count otherwise you could link Happy Days and Osmosis Jones based on the same criteria. :-)

Comment: @JacobG Well I think the difference is that Lucas made a decision in casting his film partly due to viewing the pilot Happy Days was based upon. Admittedly a tenuous link, but a link nonetheless. :)